# Unable to connect spree app with s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, spree

I have gone through many documentations but still lying on the same issue, I am trying to upload my product images on s3 locally and on heroku as well,
but not able to do so. On localhost image is getting uploaded but not reflecting on s3 bucket console and on heroku Iam encountering a error page
Please Help

*config/initializers/spree.rb*

```
Spree.config do |config|
   # Example:
   # Uncomment to override the default site name.
  #  config.site_name = "Gazella Running Costumes"
  #  config.logo = "store/rungazella.png"

  #S3 configuration
  if Rails.env.production? then
       #production. Store images on S3.
       # development will default to local storage
      attachment_config = {
      s3_credentials: {
        access_key_id: "xxx",
        secret_access_key: "xxxxx",
        bucket: "xx",
      },


      storage:        :s3,
      s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
      s3_protocol:    "https",
      bucket:         "xx",

      path:          ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      default_url:   "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      default_style: "product",
      }

      attachment_config.each do |key, value|
           Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
      end
  end
Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
end
```

*Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end 
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'     
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

I have also tried commenting out

```
path:          ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

in **spree.rb** file as per a previous post on stackoverflow but this even did not helped

Comment: what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a config/s3.yml file and add s3 config there.

```
development:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY: xxx
    AWS_SECRET_TOKEN: xxx
    AWS_BUCKET: xx
production:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
    AWS_SECRET_TOKEN: ENV['AWS_SECRET_TOKEN']
    AWS_BUCKET: ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
test:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY: xxx
    AWS_SECRET_TOKEN: xxx
    AWS_BUCKET: ''
```

In config/application.rb, add at end of file.

```
\# This constant need to be loaded before it being used in config/initializers/paperclip.rb
S3_CREDENTIALS = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'))[Rails.env]
```

Then your config/initializers/spree.rb will look something like,

```
Spree.config do |config|
end
Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
attachment_config = {
    s3_credentials: {
        access_key_id: S3_CREDENTIALS['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
        secret_access_key: S3_CREDENTIALS['AWS_SECRET_TOKEN'],
        bucket: S3_CREDENTIALS['AWS_BUCKET']
    },
    storage:        :s3,
    s3_protocol:    "http"
}
attachment_config.each do |key, value|
    Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have s3 config for development in the config file

try adding similar config for development environment by adding else part in

> ## S3 configuration
>
> if Rails.env.production? then
>
> ...
>
> end

( you can follow alternate ways, if you know)
also try posting the log, so that we can help you better.
by the way have you set heroku's environment to production ?